# Using Lodash to Compare an Object Array and Integer Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter, lodash

I have 2 pieces of data that need to be compared:

People:

```
[
 {id:1, name:"Bill"},
 {id:2, name:"Sally"},
 {id:3, name:"Steve"},
 {id:4, name:"Rick"}
]
```

Chosen:

```
[1,2,9,5]
```

I know the following can help me filter a list of people objects that have values from the chosen array:

```
_(People).indexBy('id').at(chosen).value();
```

But is it possible to do the reverse? Can I filter the `Chosen` array to only contain the id's from `People`?

Answer (score 2):

First, store the IDs in a hash. Then, filtering the chosen is trivial

```js
var hash = [
  {id:1, name:"Bill"},
  {id:2, name:"Sally"},
  {id:3, name:"Steve"},
  {id:4, name:"Rick"}
].reduce(function(hash,person) {
  hash[person.id] = true;
  return hash;
}, Object.create(null));

var result = [1,2,9,5].filter(id => id in hash);

console.log(result);
```

Unlike the naive quadratic approach, this way the cost is only linear (on average).

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`_.intersection`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.15.0#intersection) with `chosen` and an array with the `id` of `person`, via [`_.map`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.15.0#map).

```js
var people = [{ id: 1, name: "Bill" }, { id: 2, name: "Sally" }, { id: 3, name: "Steve" }, { id: 4, name: "Rick" }],
    chosen = [1, 2, 9, 5],
    result = _.intersection(chosen, _.map(people, 'id'));

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `filter()` and `find()`

```js
var arr = [
 {id:1, name:"Bill"},
 {id:2, name:"Sally"},
 {id:3, name:"Steve"},
 {id:4, name:"Rick"}
]

var chosen = [1,2,9,5];

var result = chosen.filter(function(e) {
  return arr.find(o => o.id == e);
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might as well do this job with a single reduce;

```js
var arr = [
 {id:1, name:"Bill"},
 {id:2, name:"Sally"},
 {id:3, name:"Steve"},
 {id:4, name:"Rick"}
],
chosen = [1,2,9,5],
result = arr.reduce((res,o) => { var fi = chosen.indexOf(o.id);
                                 fi !== -1 && res.push(chosen[fi]);
                                 return res;
                               },[]);
console.log(result);
```